# How much percentage of the minor signs of the Last Hour has been fulfilled?

Tags: last-day

In order to prepare ourselves before meeting with Al-Mahdi (The Guided One) and fighting against Al-Masih Ad-Dajjal (The Impostor Christ), we have to be able to estimate the arriaval of them. One way to estimate their arrival is to look at the fulfillment of the minor signs of the Last Hour because if all of the minor signs have been fulfilled (excl. arrival of Al-Mahdi) then Muslims are supposed to be strong enough to unite and stand alongside Al-Mahdi to fight against Ad-Dajjal and his minions. So how much percentage of the minor signs has been fulfilled (estimation is OK)?

Comment: This is a rather subjective question (closure reason)

Comment: @Medi1Saif is this Ok? `In order to prepare ourselves before meeting with Al-Mahdi (The Guided One) and fighting against Al-Masih Ad-Dajjal (The Impostor Christ), we have to be able to estimate the arriaval of them. One way to estimate their arrival is to look at the fulfillment of the minor signs of the Last Hour. So how much percentage of the minor signs has been fulfilled (estimation is OK)?`

Answer (score 1):

Only Allah knows about time of Last hour, this mean we can't estimate or calculate this. Even if we see a particular sign at a particular time, we don't know how much time span there is till next sign. Just remember as Allah tells it is very near.

It is important to have knowledge and understanding of signs mentioned in Hadees, so if the time comes we have knowledge to recognize Imam Mahdi. But going for time estimation and waiting for it is not right.

As for us next moment can be our last hour.